# Font Awesome 4.2.0 not rendering in IE11 with Compatibility Mode turned "On"

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-awesome

Font Awesome 4.2.0 renders perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Internet Explorer 11 (but only with Compatibility Mode turned "Off"). With Compatibility Mode turned "On" no glyphicons render. I've tried using a tried-and-true Font Awesome 4.2.0 CDN that I've used in other projects, using the Font Awesome CSS, and adding the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in the `<head>` as suggested from a GitHub post to allow the glyphs to render with Compatibility Mode turned "On". None of those solutions work and having Compatibility Mode turned "Off" is not an option for this project. So, in conclusion, my question is this. How can I have Font Awesome 4.2.0 render in Internet Explorer 11 with Compatibility Mode turned "On"?

Comment: The ironically named Compatibility Mode. I believe "Compatibility Mode" makes it effectively function as IE7, and IE7 is not supported in Font Awesome 4 (but with some effort, can be made to work with 3).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found the solution. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` needs to be placed as the **FIRST** tag in the `<head>` in order for it to work. Hope this helps anyone else who has this issue!

Comment: @ManjitSingh can you provide more information so that we may try and assist?

Comment: @racecarjonathan So here is the scenario, There was an issue in my project that font-awesome icons were not displayed in IE11, So I was looking into this thread, but unfortunately that was not the problem of font icons. :(
Actually i was using `display: table-cell;` that was not working on IE11.

Comment: Fixed my issue. It was working in IE11 - but then suddenly it wasn't (along with several other issues with our own stylesheets). Moved the tag to the, top, and problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue with IE 11 on my development machine (but not elsewhere). My Internet Options were set to not allow Font downloads. Probably won't be common, as I'm on Windows Server, but if so try this to fix it:

[Gear] >> Internet Options >> Security >> Custom Level >> Downloads >> Font Download >> Enable

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same issue. In my case, below fix works :

Firefox (and, to a lesser extent, Chrome and IE) has an issue where it fails to download the font and so doesn't display any of the icons correctly.

A very easy fix has been identified in a number of locations, cdnjs/cdnjs#755 being one of them.

The fix is to add the following to the start of the font-awesome.css file (before the @font-family call):

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Source : https://github.com/thingles/foreground/issues/222

Comment: Tried every common solution (just about all listed above) and this was the only one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same Issue and I just added the following Link in the  Tag and it worked.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Refer this to know more about why to include, you can self host the stylesheet by following this steps http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-1-using-via-google-web-fonts

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a `display: table` set on the element. Removing it resolved an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look into removing the version tags from the end of the files. Those tags cause IE to have fits.

change this...

```
../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0'
```

to this...

```
../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'
```