# Font Awesome-icons won't appear in IE11 Win7 and Shariff-Project from heise.de

Tags: html, css, fonts

I find a lot questions about Problems with not displayed Icons of Awesome font. But they didn't match my specific Problem.

I try to implement in my website a project from heise.de, called Shariff. Shariff enables website users to share their favorite content in social networtks without compromising their privacy. To realize this not the common Share- or Like-Buttons of Facebook, Twitter etc. are used.

In this project Awesome font is used for example to show the known symbols of Facebook, Twitter etc. near the share-buttons. The Awesome-font is implemented in the file shariff.css by @font-face. I have downloaded the font v=4.6.3 and have installed it on my webspace.

When viewing my demo-site with iPhone/iPad (Safari) or Chrome, I can see the symbols of Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc. But in IE11 not. To check out if my CSS has some bugs I replaced for example the twitter-symbol by an normal charakcter::
Instead of:
    .fa-twitter:before{content:"\f099"}
I used:
    .fa-twitter:before{content:"tw"}.
This is working in IE11 and I saw 'tw' before the tweet-button.

I searched the web in the last few days to find a solution for this problem in IE11, but can't find anything that works.

I guess there must be something wrong in the shariff.css where I implement Awesome font via @font-face, but I can't find the bug. So I hope someone here can help. Please be lenient with me if its just something like a missing space, bracket, etc. I'm blind and have to read the CSS-file with an voice-synth, that is in this case a bit difficult.

You will find my test-site and the CSS here:
http://www.sensitive-tiertherapie.de/test/index.htm
http://www.sensitive-tiertherapie.de/test/css/shariff.css

Unfortunately this website is in German, but if you scroll down to the bottom of that site you can see the share-buttons.

I would appreciate if someone could find-out, why it doesn't work as it should.

BTW: I hope my question will be displayed ok, because the handling of this site by screenreader isn't very smooth.

Kind regards, Michael

Comment: It looks fine: See [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5LejbIN6T8geGJfLTNiaG94NUE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks fine to me as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome 4.2.0 not rendering in IE11 with Compatibility Mode turned "On"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913012/font-awesome-4-2-0-not-rendering-in-ie11-with-compatibility-mode-turned-on)

Comment: @Arnav Borborah,

I can't have a look at your screenshot, because I'm not a sighted people. But does that mean, that you will see the icons near the buttons? If so, then it must be a local problem in my IE11-settings.

Look forward to your feedback!

Kind regards,


Michael

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your feedback, I get the solution:
It was a local accessibility setting of IE11 in:
Extras -> Options -> General -> Accessibility

Here was "ignore fonts on Website" selected. After I turned off this setting, the icons of Awesome-font appears as expected.

So if anyone get into the same trouble, check
1. compatibility mode of IE11 and
2. accessibility settings.